# Is it possible to turn off the "SAFER" option in Ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript

I have a latex program that creates an `svg` file looking like this:

```
 *** WARNING - you have selected SAFER, indicating you want Ghostscript
               to execute in a safer environment, but at the same time
               have selected DELAYBIND. Unless you use this option with
               care (and specifically, remember to call .bindnow) it is
               possible that malicious code may be able to evade the
               limited security offered by the SAFER option.

 *** WARNING - you have selected SAFER, indicating you want Ghostscript
               to execute in a safer environment, but at the same time
               have selected WRITESYSTEMDICT. Unless you use this option with
               care and specifically, remember to execute code like:
                      "systemdict readonly pop"
           <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- This file was generated by dvisvgm 2.6.3 -->
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='41.912854pt' height='2.231656pt' viewBox='219.641194 340.806823 41.912854 2.231656'>
<g id='page1' transform='matrix(1.4 0 0 1.4 0 0)'>
<path d='M157.683587 244.230465H186.0273'/>
<path d='M157.683587 244.230465H186.0273' stroke='#000' fill='none' stroke-width='1.59404' stroke-miterlimit='10'/>
</g>
</svg>
```

These warnings have only recently started coming up. It appears that I have somehow selected the `SAFER` mode in Ghostscript. Is it possible to turn this off by default?

Comment: Or maybe you updated to a newer Ghostscript version, see the [Ghostscript 9.50 Release Summary](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/News.htm). You can try parameter [`-dNOSAFER`](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#NoSafer) or deprecated parameter [`-dOLDSAFER`](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#OldSafer) which will be removed in the future. Maybe there is an option to suppress these warnings, but I couldn't find anything in the manual.

Comment: @Freddy Yeah, I've definitely upgraded to 9.50 recently, so that's probably the issue. It'd be nice if it were possible to turn these options off by default though!

Comment: This is indeed an issue introduced with GS 9.50. I've already fixed it in the dvisvgm repository and will release a new version shortly. Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do from your side  -- except downgrading to GS 9.27.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also build dvisvgm from the latest sources in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm).